# How to open new activity from bottom and hold that activity by half of screen

Tags: android

I know this look like **Shared Element Activity Transition**. But, i'm struggling to open new activity by half of screen

Please see example images. Then u can understand what i asked.

[Example- Swipe to open new activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PbUA.jpg)

[Example- Hold in half of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXzy4.jpg)

[Example- Move to top by dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuOSZ.jpg)

[Example- Showing full activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19hMU.jpg)

It may duplicate of other post. But, i couldn't find my solution exactly what i expect. So, i made question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent layout of your activity should not be of size "match_parent". If your fix the vertical size of the layout, it will only take part of the screen, while the rest in the background will be shaded just like on the screens.

Comment: Is that an answer ?

Comment: thank you! i get idea from your answer. thank you again